# Menu that takes up 100% of screen on mobile, but not desktop?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

So this is more of a general question for web design.

Let's assume I wanted to build a hamburger menu that when active, takes up 25% the width of a desktop screen, but 100% the width of a mobile screen.

How is this achievable?

Comment: Media queries..and this is too broad.

Comment: Look into Bootstrap and how it works. That will give you a good idea of how one particular library handles this issue. http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

So, for example

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .menu {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

That code will mean that the elements with the class `menu` will be width 100%, unless your screen is at least 500px wide, in which case the width will be 25%.